# Sleuth, Spring Integration and ThreadPoolExecutor: how to have one span per spawned thread?

Tags: spring-integration, threadpoolexecutor, spring-cloud-sleuth

There is an `ExecutorChannel` in my integration flow that will spawn one thread per message. The delegation chain looks like this:

`ExecutorChannel` (Spring Integration) -> `BlockingExecutor` (my own) -> `ThreadPoolExecutor` (vanilla Java)

Everything that happens in the Spring Integration part is of no interest to me. Ideally, I'd like turn off Spring Integration tracing with `spring.sleuth.integration.enabled: false` and simply annotate the method that will eventually called by the Spring Integration part with `@NewSpan`.

But when I disable spring integration, the span will appear only once: created by the main thread.

I've tried setting `spring.sleuth.integration.enabled: true` and excluding all but the relevant outbound channel via `spring.sleuth.integration.patterns`, but it's the same: only the main thread's span will appear in Zipkin.

Am I going at this from the wrong angle? What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The tracing propagation is done in Sleuth by the `TracingChannelInterceptor`. So, if you disable it, this one is not going to be applied to channels. If you see issues, then you need to apply it manually on the channel which are switching threads.

You can do that manually adding an interceptor to the channel directly or via `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` with respective pattern matching:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#global-channel-configuration-interceptors

Comment: So I could just use the existing TracingChannelInterceptor and apply it to my outgoing Channel?

Comment: Well, turns out I was looking in the wrong place completely. I was blaming the ThreadPoolExecutor / Spring Integration combination for missing spans in Zipkin.

But what really happend was they were left out by Sleuth intentionally due to the default setting of `spring.sleuth.sampler.probability`. During debugging I saw `NoopSpan`s generated instead of `RealSpan`s. As soon as I set i set it to 1.0, everything was fine.

Sorry for the misleading question.